# Which is better technique to send an image from mobile (iOS or android) to server

Tags: android, ios, utf-8, client-server, base64

Can you please suggest me the efficient encoding technique to transfer image from iphone/android to server.

**base64** encoding is too easy but i've heard it is not recommended because it increases the size of original image upto 37%

Should I use **base64 encoding**,, **UTF-8 encoding** or read and write **streams** to send image to server?

i want to use it in image sharing application which is client server app, and client will upload their images to server.

Can you also tell me other possible techniques just for knowledge?  and which one to use?

Comment: when we search about image posting on google or stackoverflow then there is base64 encoding in almost solutions, but when search about whether base64 encoding then everyone suggest to avoid it?

any clear suggestion and comparison between alternative encoding techniques will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it comes to phones especially Android streaming will be your best choice.

It's not matter what format you will choose base64 or UTF-8, eventually a stream will be opened in behind the scene.

The only thing that matters is RAM space consume by your application, if your client will try to encode it by him self before sending it, you will use more memory and some of the devices will run out of memory, this is much more impotent then the time it takes to upload the image to the server or the disc space used by server.

So my advice is: Do not manipulate the image, just stream it as-is, with the most common system tool your client can find.

Comment: when we search for the solution of image posting from client to server then we always have a results of base64 encoding and json strings.
there are rare results of byte streaming? 

stackover flow is also full of base64+json technique rather than streaming for mobile+server image posting solutions.
why is this so? any pros and cons?

Comment: @user1632984 Well base64 is the most common way and it's easy. But it ain"t the best way. I seen to many memory crushes to recommend you any other. Just Google for "android/ios stream image upload" and you will find many suggestions

Comment: Thanks Babiue for the help!  can u recommend me any link for comparison of these techniques for the knowledge and R&D purpose, along with pros and cons of each technique.